# How to highlight the div once only with jquery-ui?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, highlight

I want to animate to the document to a div and highlight it. Below is my code and it works well accept it highlights the div twice.

Any idea why? How can I just highlight the div once only?

```
$(".button-main-menu").click(function(){
     $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(".box-main-menu").offset().top }, 1000, function(){
        $(".box-main-menu").effect("highlight", {}, 1000);
     });
     return false;
});
```

Comment: What about using `$(document)` instead of `$("html, body")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using both `html` and `body` selectors, it is firing twice. So either use html or body.

`$(document)` won't work here. -**[Error Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aW4wP/2/)**

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aW4wP/1/)**

```
$(".button-main-menu").click(function(){
     $('html').animate({ scrollTop: $(".box-main-menu").offset().top }, 1000, function(){
        $(".box-main-menu").effect("highlight", {}, 1000);
     });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the jQuery `one` method - http://api.jquery.com/one/

```
$(".button-main-menu").one('click', function(){
     $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(".box-main-menu").offset().top }, 1000, function(){
         $(".box-main-menu").effect("highlight", {}, 1000);
     });
     return false;
});
```

Comment: Can you mark as the correct answer if it fixed your issue?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the selector `$("html, body")` which selects **first** `<html>` and **afterwards** it selects `<body>`.

That means, that the animations function runs **twice**.

There are 3 ways to make it work:

1. use `$("html body")` - this will select the body in the html tag.
2. use `$("body")` - this will select the body tag, since it should be there only once.
3. use `$(document)` - this will select the whole document.

In my opinion number 3 is the easiest and cleanest one.